# Can I cast two spells a round while Hasted?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Can Haste allow me to cast two spells (not quickened) in one round? This is given that haste gives an extra attack on a full round action, if I take a full round action can I cast two spells?

Answer (score 14):

## Only If Using *Haste* from *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition*

The *Player's Handbook* (2000) for *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* has on page 212-3 the spell *haste*, which reads

> ### Haste
>
> Transmutation
> **Level:** Brd 3, Sor/Wiz 3
> **Components:** V, S, M
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Target:** 1 creature
> **Duration:** 1 round/level
> **Saving Throw:** Fortitude negates (harmless)
> **Spell Resistance:** Yes (harmless)
>
> The transmuted creature moves and acts more quickly than normal. This extra speed has several effects.
>
> On his turn, the subject may take an extra partial action, either before or after his regular action.
>
> He gains a +4 haste bonus to AC. He loses this bonus whenever he would lose a dodge bonus.
>
> He can jump one and a half times as far as normal. This increase counts as an enhancement bonus.
>
> *Haste* dispels and counters *slow*.
>
> *Material Component:* A shaving of licorice root.

The *Player's Handbook* (2000) explains that

> A partial action is like a standard action, except you can't do as much. As a general rule, you can do as much with a partial action as you could with a standard action minus a move. (121)

This unhelpful description is followed a few pages later by Table 8-3: Partial Actions, which among other available options is *cast a spell* (but not spells with long casting times) (*PH* 127).

This didn't go unnoticed by *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* players for long. By *Defenders of the Faith* (May 2001), the necessity of *haste* was so severe that the following armor special ability was published therein:

> **Speed:** This armor or shield enchantment provides a +4 haste bonus to AC and gives the wearer an extra partial action every round, as the *haste* spell. This armor seems to be constantly vibrating, always appearing blurred. *Caster Level:* 5th; *Prerequisites:* Craft Magic Arms and Armor, *haste*; *Market Price:* +3 bonus.

This is an ability that all but the newest contemporary *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* player recognizes as ridiculously powerful, but at the time it wasn't *overpowered*, and instead an effort to equalize the haves (wizards *et al.*) and have-nots (everyone except wizards *et al.*).

This was changed by the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* revision, but--for a few years, anyway--the spell *haste* did, indeed, allow the casting of multiple spells per turn.

---

**Older Editions**

- The *Player's Handbook* (1989, 1999) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition* in its description of the spell *haste* says, "Spellcasting and spell effects are *not* sped up" (192). Emphasis theirs.
- The *Player's Handbook* (1978) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* in its description of the spell *haste* says, "Spell casting is not more rapid" (74).

Answer (score 7):

No. Casting a spell is usually a standard action, though some are cast as Move, Swift, or Immediate instead. The effect of Haste reads "When making a full attack action, a hasted creature may make one extra attack with any weapon he is holding." It states specifically that it only has an effect when making a full attack action, and the effect it has is that it grants one extra attack (it goes on further to note that it doesn't stack with the Speed enchantment and such, but that's not relevant to your question.)

In short, because the Haste spell doesn't grant you extra standard, move, or swift actions and because it doesn't specifically say it allows you to cast extra spells, using Haste doesn't allow you to cast more spells in a given round than you otherwise would.

Answer (score 3):

No: from the [on-line SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm)

> nor does it actually grant an extra action, so you can’t use it to cast a second spell or otherwise take an extra action in the round.

This was the case from OD&D through to at least early 3.5e, with the exception of D&D 3e.

If I can venture an opinion, because of the way Vancian magic works this is a little like asking whether you can ask me to drive to your house twice as quickly because you have haste cast on you. Magic is like electricity and flows through the "circuit" created by your verbal, somatic, and material components at a set rate determined by those components, not the speed at which you perform them; and in fact hurrying them will prevent the spell working at all (if you're lucky and the DM doesn't roll for a chance that the spell will backfire :) ).

Comment: hmmm it's maybe because it didn't make sense to us to be that FAST (as implied by being hasted) and be able to just do one standard action and... laugh and admire your work for the rest of the round. i guess i have to think of a workaround then

Comment: with regards to your additional edit, won't that electricity flowing through your circuits actually flow faster FOR you since you are hasted versus another person un-hasted. sure they are both given set amount of time, yours just functions in a FASTER time reference. much like two planets spinning at different rates. 1 hour here (hasted) can mean 1 year to another planet spinning slower (un-hasted)?

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that YOU might be faster but the socket on the wall isn't affected by that and is still 240V (or whatever your local voltage may be - YVMV!). And, actually, if you take the relative view then the outside world is going slower for you, not faster. "All computers wait at the same speed" as they say.

Comment: actually going with that logic, my DM actually said it should affect not just my spells, but also spell effects on me (since they too will be subject to the relative difference of my time frame against the outside) effectively halving their duration. to me they will be going the whole duration but to others it burns off faster. i caved in after that hahaha

Comment: What is the URL for the online SRD?

Comment: @briddums [Official site (RTF format)](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35), and various online adaptations: [d20SRD](http://d20srd.org), [DnD SRD](http://dndsrd.net), [D&D Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:System_Reference_Document).

Comment: For this explanation to make sense, you would have to not be able to cast spells while under the effects of Time Stop or similar.  Better explanation is that haste speeds the body, but not the mind.

Comment: @Perkins. That's a consequence of an error in the description of Time Stop that was introduced in 3e; the spell was not supposed to speed you up, it was supposed to stop everyone else. Why they made the change in the text I can't imagine but you're right in saying that it introduces a contradiction with Haste. However, Haste must speed up the mind otherwise hasted characters would be horribly clumsy.

Comment: @Nagora  They probably made the change because a spell that stops the entire universe just seems like it would need a ludicrous amount of power compared to one that just makes the caster move really fast.  Since it doesn't make any difference from the caster's point of view, the change lets it not seem like it should be allowing the entire universe a will save.